# Using slug in CakePHP v3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I plan to upgrade my CakePHP v2 to v3 website. So I start to learn by looking at the Blog tutorial & it work fine.

Next, I start to customize base on my CakePHP v2 site.

The first thing I would like to do is using slug in URL instead of id. I add slug column in database.

But I always get an error when I click the url with the slug. The error is

Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$created [APP/Template/Articles/view.ctp, line 3]

Help on this is greatly appreciated.

This is my routes

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index']);

$routes->connect('/articles/:slug', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view'], ['pass' => ['slug']]);
```

This is my controller

```
public function index()
{
     $this->set('articles', $this->Articles->find('all'));
}


public function view($slug = null)
{
    $article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug);
    $this->set(compact('article'));
}
```

This is my index.ctp

```
<h1>Blog articles</h1>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Slug</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $article->id ?></td>
    <td>
        <?= $this->Html->link($article->title, ['action' => 'view', $article->slug]) ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?= $article->created ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?= $article->slug ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` method returns a query object. Since you want the single entity that matches that slug, call `first()` on the query object:

```
$article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->first();
```

Comment: TQVM. I also find out that this will work also -  $article = $this->Articles->find()->where(['slug' => $slug])->first();